# I have solved this problem. But I am not sure, whether I did any mistakes. Would you please have a look at my problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]I am not sure about the second last line. please guide me.

Comment: Please delete the image from your posting and use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) instead, to express all of the Math.

Comment: Is it forbidden to share handwriting here? I am new in this forum, so don't know the rules properly.

Comment: It's not "forbidden" exactly, but "the approved style" is to type things in "TeX", that MathJax will typeset, etc. Photos of mathematical symbols (whether handwritten or already typeset) simply don't work very well...

Comment: It also doesn't work well for those of impaired vision that may be using screen readers. Please typeset with MathJax and provide a descriptive title.

Comment: Math in photos is not searchable.  Also, the Math is generally more difficult to read.  MathJax is fairly straightforward.